# Commenting/skipping markup with Smarty

Tags: php, templates, smarty

Is there a smarty tag that allows skipping content in a template without the enclosed code showing up in the rendered HTML page?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do you mean something like the Comment Tag?

```
{* Comment *}
```

Your question is a bit difficult to understand or do you mean a minifying?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks. I wasn't able to find it but apparently it's mentionned somewhere basic syntax. It would have been surprising if such a tag didn't exist :)

Comment: In Showare6 the twig engine is used. Comments now are {# the content #}